# Search for an exact part of sentence in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, full-text-search, where-clause

I have a PostgreSQL database table with rows containing some sentences / paragraphs of text.

Lets say there are three records (nonsensical, just for example):

```
1) A dancing fox ran across the road.
2) I like dancing foxtrot.
3) These animals are foxes.
```

I would like to search for "dancing fox" and I expect it should return "record 1" only.

However, when I'll use wildcarded `%dancing fox%` LIKE syntax, I'll retrieve records 1 and 2.

I expeced that ts_vector could be a solution, but the project uses more locales (problem 1) and I do not want it match the third record - I don't want a real fulltext (problem 2).

What would you suggest to use, please? Or do you have any experiences or links to sources how to deal with problems 1 and 2?

I know my question is quite confusing, so thank you for your patience. Maybe I just need to get pushed in a right direction.

Comment: Could you add leading/lagging space to your wildcard search?

Comment: "I expeced that ts_vector could be a solution, but the project uses more locales (problem 1)"  Can you explain in more detail, perhaps with examples, what about this would be a problem?

Comment: @jjanes I expected that "simple" dictionary/search configuration also contains locale-specific stopwords etc., but it does not seem to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use full text searching with the 'simple' configuration to avoid language-specific stemming and stop words, and with the phrase match operators to maintain word order and spacing.

```
select * from foo 
    where to_tsvector('simple',x)  @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple','dancing fox');
```

You say you don't want to match the 3rd example, but it is not clear why it would do so in the first place, even you were using 'english' and `plainto_tsquery` rather than 'simple' and `phraseto_tsquery`.

You are still at the mercy of what default FTS text parser considers to be a word, but none of your examples touch on this point (what if fox-trot were hyphenated?)

This will be supported by the usual FTS indexes on tsvector types.

Or as GMB suggest, you can use `~` and '\y'.  This type of query will be supported by pg_trgm indexes.  I think this solution is more intuitive, but if the texts involved are long it might be less efficient.

Comment: I have to deal with hyphenated compound words and I want to find "dancing-fox", but not "dancing fox-trot" so I would use phraseto_tsquery. I will also probably create a special text search configuration coming from simple (because of unaccent, I didnt mention it before, because I expected to store two variants of texts - with and without accents). Your answer seems to match my requirements well, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a regexp.

The word boundaries `\y` come handy: there may be other characters than a space that delimit words.

```
where mycol ~ '\ydancing fox\y'
```

As [explained in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE): *`\y` matches only at the beginning or end of a word*.

Answer (score 2):

You can add delimiters:

```
where concat(' ', col, ' ') like '% dancing fox %'
```

Comment: Why the concat? Is this to account for the chance that the entire value is just `dancing fox`?

Comment: This will not find it at the end of the sentence before punctuation.